# How to add more quickly add 1 million triples in Sesame 2.7.7

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, sesame

I've noticed that the instantiation using the the RepositoryConnection method `add` was slower than when instantiated by modifying the model using a SPARQL query.  Despite the difference, even the SPARQL update method takes a long time for instantiation (3.4 minutes to 10,000 triplets). The execution of multiple `insert`s (one query for each triple) or one big `insert` query does not change the performance of the methods. It is still slow. Is there another method appropriate for adding 1 million triples, or are there any special configurations that can help?

#### Code for RepositoryConnection

```
Repository myRepository = new HTTPRepository(serverURL, repositoryId);
myRepository.initialize();
RepositoryConnection con = myRepository.getConnection();
ValueFactory f = myRepository.getValueFactory();

i = 0;
j = 1000000;    

while(i < j)(
    URI event    = f.createURI(ontologyIRI + "event"+i);
    URI hasTimeStamp    = f.createURI(ontologyIRI + "hasTimeStamp");
    Literal timestamp   = f.createLiteral(fields.get(0));
    con.add(event, hasTimeStamp, timestamp);
    i++
}
```

#### Code for SPARQL

```
Repository myRepository = new HTTPRepository(serverURL, repositoryId);
myRepository.initialize();
RepositoryConnection con = myRepository.getConnection();

i = 0;
j = 1000000;    

while(i < j)(
    query = "INSERT {";
    query += "st:event"+i+" st:hasTimeStamp     '"+fields.get(0)+"'^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .\n"
    + "}"
      + "WHERE { ?x ?y ?z }";
    Update update = con.prepareUpdate(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, query);
    update.execute();

    i++;
}
```

**Edition**
I've done experiment with `In Memory` and `Native Store` Sesame repositories with synchronization value equal to 0

Comment: You have said anything about what the backend storage is or the configuration of it.  Sesame is a framework that supports various storage backends e.g. native and disk as well as third party backends like OWLIM.  The backend used and the configuration of it may be an important factor here.

Comment: The way it's written, this question may be off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's asking for "opinion about the performance of Sesame when instantiating RDF triples" and "looking for the most suitable methods", but "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."  That said, you've got a particular piece of code here and have some numbers about performance, so it's probably answerable.  You'll need to provide more information…

Comment: The code you show for using RepositoryConnection.add only inserts one triple, so I am not sure how you can conclude from that that insert of multiple triples will be slow. Suffice to say that if you need 3.4 minutes to insert 10,000 triples, you are doing something seriously wrong (or you have _very_ limited hardware, or a backend configuration that is not suited for quick updates). You will need to be a bit more precise about what you're trying to do and how, exactly you're doing it (for example, are you using Sesame's transaction mechanism correctly?)

Comment: Also: the code snippets you show are incomplete. Since you are using a variable `i` in several places, I suspect that you have a loop in there somewhere in your actual code. To be able to answer what you're doing wrong, you need to show that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I only just noticed that you added the requested additional info, hence this rather late reply)

The problem is, as I suspected, that you are not using transactions to batch your update operations together. Effectively, each add operation you do becomes a single transaction (a Sesame repository connection by default runs in autocommit mode), and this is slow and ineffecient.

To change this, start a transaction (using `RepositoryConnection.begin()`), then add your data, and finally call `RepositoryConnection.commit()` to finalize the transaction.

Here's how you should modify your first code example:

```
Repository myRepository = new HTTPRepository(serverURL, repositoryId);   
myRepository.initialize(); 
RepositoryConnection con = myRepository.getConnection(); 
ValueFactory f = myRepository.getValueFactory();

i = 0; 
j = 1000000;    

try {
  con.begin(); // start the transaction
  while(i < j) {
      URI event    = f.createURI(ontologyIRI + "event"+i);
      URI hasTimeStamp    = f.createURI(ontologyIRI + "hasTimeStamp");
      Literal timestamp   = f.createLiteral(fields.get(0));
      con.add(event, hasTimeStamp, timestamp);
      i++; 
  }
  con.commit(); // finish the transaction: commit all our adds in one go.
}
finally {
  // always close the connection when you're done with it. 
  con.close();
}
```

The same applies to your code with the SPARQL update. For more information on how to work with transactions, have a look at the Sesame manual, particularly [the chapter about using the Repository API](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#The_Repository_API).

As an aside: since you're working over HTTTP, there is a risk that if your transaction becomes too large, it will start consuming a lot of memory in your client. If this starts happening you may want to break up your update into several transactions. But with an update consisting of a million triples you should still be alright I think.